# Porque está dando erro ao tentar compilar o programa com essa biblioteca (IUP)?

Tags: c

Ao incluir uma biblioteca C está dando esse erro ao tentar compilar

> ```
> ||=== Build: Release in iup (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
> obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| multiple definition of `WindowProcedure(HWND__*, unsigned int, unsigned int, long)@16'|
> obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| first defined here|
> obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| multiple definition of `WinMain@16'|
> obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| first defined here|
> ld.exe||cannot find -lbgi|
> ld.exe||cannot find -liup|
> ld.exe||cannot find -liupcontrols|
> ld.exe||cannot find -lcd|
> ld.exe||cannot find -liupcd|
> ||=== Build failed: 9 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
> ```

Não é a primeira vez que tenho esse tipo de problema ao tentar usar bibliotecas nos meus programas. Configurei as pastas no linker/compilador, mas não está dando certo. Estou usando o Code Blocks, mas já tentei no Dev-C++ e Netbeans e também tive problemas.

A biblioteca que estou usando é [essa](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/) e o programa que tentei compilar e esse:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iup.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  IupOpen(&argc, &argv);

  IupMessage("Hello World 1", "Hello world from IUP.");

  IupClose();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Atualização:
Estou utilizando o Windows 10 x64 com o compilador MingW.

Eu segui o passo-a-passo, coloquei a biblioteca na pasta do compilador e incluí o arquivo de cabeçalho tanto na hierarquia do projeto quanto na configuração do compilador. Apesar disso esta dando esse erro:

> ```
> "/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
> make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Carlos/Documents/NetBeansProjects/IUP'
> "/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/iup.exe
> make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Carlos/Documents/NetBeansProjects/IUP'
> mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
> gcc     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/iup build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o -L/C/MinGW/lib -liup -liupcontrols -lcd -liupcd -lcomctl32 -lole32 -g -I/C/MinGW/include -include /C/MinGW/include/iup.h
> build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
> C:\Users\Carlos\Documents\NetBeansProjects\IUP/main.c:6: undefined reference to `IupOpen'
> C:\Users\Carlos\Documents\NetBeansProjects\IUP/main.c:8: undefined reference to `IupMessage'
> C:\Users\Carlos\Documents\NetBeansProjects\IUP/main.c:10: undefined reference to `IupClose'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/iup.exe] Error 1
> make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Carlos/Documents/NetBeansProjects/IUP'
> make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
> make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Carlos/Documents/NetBeansProjects/IUP'
> make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
> ```

Comment: Tente dar um título mais descritivo para sua pergunta, pode ser a diferença entre atrair a atenção de quem sabe a resposta, ou não...

Comment: Poste mais detalhes de como você está compilando o código. Este código é o exemplo da documentação do projeto IUP, então deveria funcionar. Observe que você precisa de várias libs, instaladas e com acesso para poder compilar, caso seja compilação em linux.

Comment: Utilizei todas as respostas, mas ainda não consegui resolver. Mas vou continuar tentando. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Mesmo após feitas alterações no processo de compilação, é possível que o erro persista, pois compiladores são otimizados para alterar os arquivos compilados o mínimo possível. Portanto, arquivos-objeto e linkados (.o, .obj) podem ainda conter erros que já foram corrigidos!

Experimente, após cada mudança, deletar tais arquivos e recompilar do zero, para evitar erros persistentes. Ao superar esse erro, termine a prática.

Answer (score 1):

Para essa biblioteca funcionar você deve colocar a biblioteca na pasta do compilador e adicionar as configurações que indica no Linker/Compilador...
Olha ai esse passo a passo:
http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~mgattass/cg/trbDicas/iup/PassoAPassoIUP.html